# Android use <shape> to set view background,solid not work

Tags: android, background, shapes

when I use

```
<corners android:radius="12dp" /> 
<solid android:color="#ffffff" />
```

to set radius,the solid worked, but when I use

```
<corners android:bottomLeftRadius="12dp"
             android:bottomRightRadius="12dp" />
<solid android:color="#ffffff" />
```

to set bottom radius, the "solid" not worked
It is happend on One plus 6.0.1
I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set `radius` to the `bottomLeft` and `bottomRight` only. You should try this way:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:radius="12dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp" />
</shape>
```

You can have a look on [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/2T1u5fs-Umw) for more about using **shape** and **selector** in Android View

Comment: but why it only happend on a few devices，such as One plus 6.0.1

Comment: With your way, it didn't work with my devices(Nexus and Galaxy J6)